# how to change image filenames using javascript

Tags: javascript, seo, filenames

I'm working a site that has over 50,000 products within its database. The problem is that the file names are as cryptic as this problem: 51h5zpsj7il and another was: 51i5cvruyrl. I need to change these to more SEO friendly names such as "Introduction-to-Programming" or "C++-for-Everyone". The client sells their products on Amazon and therefore grabs these image names from them. I've already written the code to change the alt, but I don't know how to rename a file that isn't ours. Am I able to come up with a technique to have these files added to their imgs and then work from there?

For convienenvce, this is the JS code for changing the alt text, not the src text to which needs to be changed for SEO:

`var title = document.getElementById("product-description").getElementByClassName("product-title")[0].innerHTML,
    img = document.getElementById("main-image").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt=title;`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're pointing to an image file on Amazon's servers, which have random image names.  You pretty much summed it up when you said, "I don't know how to rename a file that isn't ours."  It's not yours, thus you can't.

What you'd need to do is copy those images to your own server, where you can name them whatever you like.  Or, perhaps write some code on your own server that processes a *friendly* image name then does a `301 REDIRECT` to the correct image on Amazon.  The latter approach would save you from having to store the images yourself.

I do question why you want to rename the images.  My knowledge on SEO isn't extensive, but I see no advantages of using friendly image names within HTML.  As long as the page URLs themselves are friendly, you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but what type of code would I use to do a 301 request to grab the related image?

Comment: @BenMorgan - I don't know, since I don't know what server side language you're using.